# Toggle aria-expanded between true and false with javascript

Tags: javascript, accessibility, wai-aria

I am trying to toggle an aria tag between true and false when a button is clicked. I've tried several implementations which seems to do absolutely nothing. Below is what I am currently using which successfully toggles the class. How can I extend this to toggle the aria-expanded value between true and false? Be easy on me, I am transitioning from jQuery to ES6.

```
const theTrigger = document.getElementById('mobile-form-control');
const theForm = document.querySelectorAll('.l-header__mobile-form');

theTrigger.onclick = function () {
  for (const x of theForm) {
    x.classList.toggle('show');
  }
};
```

Comment: I pasted the wrong bit of code :/  I've updated my question.

Comment: ARIA attributes are no different than other HTML attributes and can be changed with setAttribute() as @connexo recommended.

Comment: On StackOverflow, you are required to manage your questions' lifecycle. That means, that if you get answers, and they solve your problem, pick the answer that answers it best. If not, comment on the answers given and explain why these do not help you solve your problem.

Answer (score 7):

It would be much easier with a simple toggle:

```js
    x.ariaExpanded = !x.ariaExpanded;
```

But weirdly, Firefox doesn't support direct boolean access to the DOM property! 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/ariaExpanded#browser_compatibility

So I ended up with something like this:

```js
    x.setAttribute(
      'aria-expanded', 
      `${x.getAttribute('aria-expanded') !== 'true'}`
    );
```

---

**Edit:** Since Firefox 119 ([see usage stats](https://caniuse.com/?search=ariaExpanded)), you can directly use the property instead of the `getAttribute` string, <s>like in the first code block above</s>.
**Edit2:** While `setAttribute` and `getAttribute` are indeed no longer needed, `x.ariaExpanded` does indeed return a string, not a boolean, thanks @adam-johnson.
So the definitive answer is now this:

```js
    x.ariaExpanded = x.ariaExpanded !== 'true';
```

Comment: While this syntax didn't work for my specific situation (`ariaExpanded` returns a string), a [very similar syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69888926/908059) in a similar question did.

TIL `ariaExpanded`! So happy we have that now.

Comment: @adam-johnson: Thanks, you are right! I edited my answer with the correct fix.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming `x` in your for-loop is the element you want to toggle the `aria-expanded` attribute on:

```js
theTrigger.onclick = function () {
  for (const x of theForm) {
    x.classList.toggle('show');
    x.setAttribute(
      'aria-expanded', 
      `${(x.getAttribute('aria-expanded') !== 'true').toString()}` 
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: This should be marked as the right answer!