# Toggle aria-expanded with ES6 JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I am trying to toggle an aria tag between `true` and `false` when a button is clicked. I've tried several implementations which seem to do absolutely nothing. Below is what I am currently using which successfully toggles the class. How can I extend this to toggle the aria-expanded value between `true` and `false`? Be easy on me, I am transitioning from jQuery to ES6.

```
const theTrigger = document.getElementById('mobile-form-control');
const theForm = document.querySelectorAll('.l-header__mobile-form');

theTrigger.onclick = function () {
  for (const x of theForm) {
    x.classList.toggle('show');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can toggle the attribute by comparing its value with `'true'`.

```
x.ariaExpanded = x.ariaExpanded !== 'true';
```

Comment: Wow! That was much simpler then I thought! Thank you. TIL.

Comment: @RobertE Happy to help.